# dhtmlxGantt not loading from database

Tags: php, mysql, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I am using dhtmlxGantt to produce Gantt charts from a database.  I have been through the tutorial and the in-line chart displays fine. When I then pull in data from a database the html page times out and displays nothing.

If i load the data.php file it displays the data from the database instantly. I have found that if i try and display both the in-line data and the database data then the in-line loads instantly and then about 8 seconds later the data from db table loads?. Also the links from the database data don't show. Can anyone help please?

code from myGantt.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:10px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }   
</style>
<head>
   <title>How to Start with dhtmlxGantt</title>
   <script src="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>   
   <link href="codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:1000px; height:400px;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var tasks = {
    data:[
        {id:1, text:"Test Project 1",start_date:"01-04-2013", duration:35,
        progress: 0.1, open: true},
        {id:2, text:"Wire Framing",   start_date:"03-04-2013", duration:5, 
        progress: 0,   open: true, parent:1},
        {id:3, text:"Design",   start_date:"10-04-2013", duration:20, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1},
        {id:4, text:"Database Design", start_date:"10-04-2013", duration:5, 
        progress: 0,   open: true, parent:1},
        {id:5, text:"System Set up", start_date:"11-04-2013", duration:2, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1},
        {id:6, text:"System Presentation", start_date:"24-04-2013", duration:1, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1},
    {id:7, text:"Testing", start_date:"25-04-2013", duration:5, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1},
    {id:8, text:"Bug Fixing", start_date:"30-04-2013", duration:5, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1},
    {id:9, text:"Beta Launch", start_date:"05-05-2013", duration:1, 
        progress: 0.0, open: true, parent:1}
    ],
    links:[
        {id:1, source:1, target:2, type:"1"},
        {id:2, source:1, target:3, type:"1"},
        {id:3, source:1, target:4, type:"1"},
        {id:4, source:1, target:5, type:"1"},
        {id:5, source:1, target:6, type:"1"},
    {id:6, source:1, target:7, type:"1"},
    {id:7, source:1, target:8, type:"1"},
    {id:8, source:1, target:9, type:"1"}
    ]
};   
//  gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"; 

    gantt.init("gantt_here");   
    gantt.parse(tasks);
            gantt.load("data.php");
//  var dp=new dataProcessor("data.php");   
//  dp.init(gantt);

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The data.php file is:

```
<?php


define('DB_USER','projects_test');
define('DB_PASS','user_pass'); 
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

include ('codebase/connector/gantt_connector.php');
// include ("./config.php");

$res=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 
mysql_select_db("projects_test");

$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res);

$gantt->render_links("gantt_links","id","source,target,type");

 $gantt->render_table(
    "gantt_tasks",
    "id",
    "start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent"    
);

?>
```

The link to the php file is: 
http://dev.subzerostudio.com/dhtmlxGantt/data.php

The output can be seen at:

http://dev.subzerostudio.com/dhtmlxGantt/myGantt.html

Answer (score 2):

This line helped me

```
gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000940/Creating-your-own-online-Gantt-application-with-dh

My full code:

```
gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
gantt.init("gantt_here", new Date(2010,7,1), new Date(2010,8,1));
// refers to the 'data' action that we will create in the next substep
gantt.load("./data");
//  refers to the 'data' action as well
var dp = new gantt.dataProcessor("./data");
dp.init(gantt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because there is to much data to load. It's certainly a problem when you are loading your data. Look your div with class "gantt_task_row" and gannt_task_row_odd" there is nearly 39000 nodes...
On the tutorial, the give the parameter "json" to parse, maybe it's the root of your problem

Comment: Hi Quentin - I am loading from a database and the 2 tables have respectively 9 and 8 records.  You can see the db output if you run the link with data.php - so not sure where the 39,000 nodes come from?  Thanks Nigel

Comment: Can you try to only use the js data, and after only those from your DataBase. I'm quite sure your problem it's because the framework/parser doesn't understand well your data

Comment: Hi Quentin - the db structure is exactly the same as in the example so there is no reason why the parser wont understand the data.  I was using an existing db with other tables.  Now I have created a db called 'gantt' and with the two tables created using the code from step 5.  I have then filled it with a small amount of valid data - so it should be working......

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same issue I have figured out and resolved both problems.  The reason I couldn't get the data from the database to display was simply that i had set the parent node to 1 for ALL entries - changing the first one to 0 resolved the problem.

The delay of 8 seconds was the fact that data was being drawn in from the inline elements and the db and the date formats were different.  therefore the Gantt was trying to display over 100 years of data.......

All now working.

Comment: The id of root node can be changed in configuration, e.g. gantt.config.root_id = 1;
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_root_id_config.html
Regarding the delay, currently gantt has couple of settings that will speed-up rendering of big datasets. 
Simplified timeline layout:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_show_task_cells_config.html or http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_static_background_config.html
dynamic loading:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_branch_loading_config.html